# how to get the full path and store it in a variable

Tags: php

I would to create a program that upload a file and whatever it is inside the file i would output it through the use of the textarea. But my problem is I can't get the full path of the uploaded file due to security of the browser. I tried using this [How to get the path of a file before its uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481927/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-file-before-its-uploaded) as a reference but it only show the fakepath. Main problem is I can't get the full path to store it in a variable. Any idea how to do this?

Im using this code to get the file name

```
<?php      
        if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
        {
        $fileName = $_POST['file']; 
        $fullPath = (realpath).$fileName;

        --here there must be a variable that will hold the fullpath but the $fullPath is wrong way to declare.

        echo $fullPath."\n\n";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Err, isn't it just in `$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: As noted above, you use be tmp_name from the $_FILES array, then you set where you want it to save to.

Comment: you don't need the path, only the filename itself